# The recursive formula for generalized pentagonal numbers characteristic function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recursion

I am investigating the pentagonal number characteristic function. For the generalized pentagonal numbers the formula is known: $$p_n=n(3n\pm1)/2$$
The first few generalized pentagonal numbers are:
$${0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 15, 22, 26, 35, 40, 51, 57, 70, 77}$$
The characteristic function is:
$${1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}$$
I am trying to find a way to represent the characteristic function in a recursive way. Frankly saying I was not able even to find a way to start this. I have looked at the wolfram, wikipedia and oeis to find anything related to this. But nothing found.

Comment: Even if it does not bring any answer to your question, see this [very nice text](https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/PentagonalNumbers.pdf) about pentagonal numbers, Ferrer's diagrams, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the generalized pentagonal number pairs: $(3r^2-r)/2$ and $(3r^2+r)/2$ starting with $r=1$.

r| pair
1| 1,2
2| 5,7
3| 12,15
and continue

If $cr$ is the characteristic function let $cr(0) = 1$.
Each of the pair of pentagonal numbers are the index for the characteristic function and the sign is = $(-1)^r$ .
If $cr$ is the characteristic function:

$cr(1) = cr (2) = -1$

$cr(5) = cr (7) =  1$

$cr (12) = cr (15) =-1$
etc.

cr (Non Pentagonal #s > 0) = 0